# Glossary of oil and gas industry geophysical terms

Tags: geophysics, petroleum

Reviewing market regulatory standards I came across the problem of finding a source that I could cite of concise, worldwide accepted industry geophysical terms.

So far I know Schlumberger Oilfield Glossary, SEG Wiki, SPE PetroWiki that give some information on some terms. In practice I need something like this definition in [SEG Wiki](http://wiki.seg.org/wiki/Dictionary:Crooked_line) for seismic crooked lines. Although in this case I don't think the term is well defined.

I am looking for a worldwide industry accepted glossary that I could rely on and cite. The broader it is the best will be for having less problems in future. Where would be the best place to find such source of information? Any other suggestions will be welcome.

Comment: The main limitation may be that you are looking for something which is "worldwide" and different regulatory agencies may have differing term definitions. My personal advice would be to cite based on whatever the prevailing country or regulatory definition is and add a glossary at the end of your report if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Sheriff's *Encyclopedic Dictionary* is the closest thing to a canonical text, but the Schlumberger glossary is more up to date.**

[Sheriff](http://wiki.seg.org/wiki/Dictionary:Sheriff's_Dictionary) is a scientific text, whereas the Schlumberger glossary is a little more generally accessible, but neither is comprehensive. Sheriff is especially poor on recent advances. On the plus side, you can edit it, if you're an SEG member.

After those two, Wikipedia is probably your next best bet.